# close appending to aliased newcommands

Tags: macros

I have:

```
\newcommand{\alias}[0]{POS}
```

and use it as:

```
... \alias ...
```

I want to sometimes pluralize it, output as: ...POSs...

but this (obviously) doesn't work:

```
... \aliass ...
```

nor does this:

```
... \alias\s ...
```

nor does anything else I've tried. Presumably this is easy.

---

Never mind -- I figured it out but I don't know how to delete a question.

Comment: And `\alias s`? (a blank space in between).

Comment: If it was a valid question, the appropriate thing would be to post your solution as an answer and accept it instead of removing the question, as it might help future visitors.

Comment: Consider rolling back your question then include a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) to illustrate a use case then and post your solution as an answer in the **Your Answer** box. And [welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)